# Как зафиксировать фон из градиента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```
body{
  position: relative;    
}
body::before {    
    background-size: cover; 
    content: ' ';
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Если я добавляю класс с изображением, то все отлично - оно фиксировано и никуда не двигается, а если с градиентом, то почему-то перемещается.

Градиент:

```
 body.gradient2 {       
    background: rgb(208,228,247);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%, rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
}
```

Изображение:

```
body.newyear_night {
  background-image: url("/images/fon/43.jpg");    
}
```

Добавляю класс я вот так:

```
document.body.classList.add('gradient2');
document.body.classList.add('newyear_night');
```

Comment: что значит перемещается? вы можете воспроизвести проблему в фидл?

Comment: т.е. прокручивается вместе с текстом.. и получается некрасиво в итоге. Как сказать.. ну вот если бы это был не градиент, а простая картинка. И прокручивая текст картинка-фон также перемещалась, а внизу создавалась новая..

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.classList.add('gradient2');
```

```css
html {
  height: 1000px; /*100% для динамики*/
}
body{
  background-size: cover;
}
body.gradient2 {       
    background: rgb(208,228,247);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%, rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
}
```

Comment: не работает.. также повторяется.. почему-то картинки вот фиксированы, а градиент нет

Comment: "Использование background-attachment : fixed каждый раз при прокрутке вызывает операцию перерисовки. Страница должна переместить свое содержимое. И когда дело доходит до фиксированного фона, браузер должен заново прорисовать картинку в новом месте, относительно существующих DOM-элементов." но у меня как раз-таки нет "background-attacment" и картинки занового не прорисовываются, в отличие от градиента

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Решение очень простое - необходимо добавлять класс не к `body`, а к `body::before` вот таким образом:

```
body.gradient2::before {       
    background: rgb(208,228,247);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%, rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%, rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%, rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(208,228,247,1) 0%,rgba(115,177,231,1) 24%,rgba(10,119,213,1) 100%,rgba(135,188,234,1) 100%); 
}
```